# could not identify an equality operator for type json[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
SELECT some_data
       new_table.data
  FROM some_table
  JOIN (SELECT array_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', food_item.id,
        'name', name,
        'fiber', fiber * (serving->>'scaling_factor')::real,
        'serving', serving
      ) as data, id) FROM private_table) new_table on new_table.id = some_table.id
WHERE time = '12:00'
GROUP BY new_table.data
```

end it fails with error:

> could not identify an equality operator for type json[]

Comment: Convert the JSON to a string and compare that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT some_data
       new_table.data
  FROM some_table
  JOIN (SELECT array_agg(jsonb_build_object(
        'id', food_item.id,
        'name', name,
        'fiber', fiber * (serving->>'scaling_factor')::real,
        'serving', serving
      ) as data, id) FROM private_table) new_table on new_table.id = some_table.id
WHERE time = '12:00'
GROUP BY new_table.data
```

[demo:db<>dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7f7c27f93287bb6b7ea21f432ae95fb5)

You could work with type `jsonb` instead which supports comparison (e.g. by creating the JSON using `jsonb_build_object()`)

OR

You can cast from type `text` or `jsonb` back into type `json` afterwards:

```
SELECT
    some_data,
    data::json as data
FROM (
   -- your query
) s
```

Comment: The `group by` needs to go into the derived table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT some_data
       new_table.data::text
  FROM some_table
  JOIN (SELECT array_agg(json_build_object(
        'id', food_item.id,
        'name', name,
        'fiber', fiber * (serving->>'scaling_factor')::real,
        'serving', serving
      ) as data, id) FROM private_table) new_table on new_table.id = some_table.id
WHERE time = '12:00'
GROUP BY new_table.data:text
```